# css - How do I defind style for this structure

Tags: html, css

```
<h3 class="st-module-heading">
      <span>
         <span>Lastest Products</span>
      </span>
</h3>
```

I want to defind css for span element contain content "Latest Products".
How will do do? Thanks so much.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to give the span a class:

```
<h3 class="st-module-heading">
      <span>
         <span class='myspan'>Lastest Products</span>
      </span>
</h3>
```

Then in CSS, depending on how specific or general you need to be:

```
.myspan { ... }

/*or*/

span.myspan { ... }

/*or*/

h3.st-module-heading span.myspan { ... }
```

Without a specific class defined, you would need to do this:

```
h3.st-module-heading span span { ... }
```

Which selects the `<span>` inside the `<span>` inside `<h3 class=st-module-heading>`.

But why the extra `<span>`? In your current code, it is not doing anything. You could just as easily remove it all together unless you are going to need it for something.

Either way, here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jELPP/) to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

the selector should be:

```
h3.st-module-heading span {
}
```

html:

```
<h3 class="st-module-heading">
     <span>Lastest Products</span>     
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that exact structure (the two nested spans), you can use the following css to only select the second nested span:

HTML:

```
<h3 class="st-module-heading">
      <span>
         <span>Lastest Products</span>
      </span>
</h3>
```

CSS:

```
.st-module-heading>span>span {
    /* Your css here */
}
```

The `>` is the child selector - so `.st-module-heading>span>span` literally means 'select the span which is **directly** inside another span, which is **directly** inside the element with the class st-module-heading'.

You could simply use `.st-module-heading span span` if need be - but that may not suit if you have additional nested spans.

Link to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianlynch/bmm6p/1/).